# Why do Dagger components have to declare their scope?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

Why do I have to annotate a Dagger component with the scopes it's going to use? Why is it not enough to annotate the class itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because scopes by themselves don't mean anything. It's the components and their relationships that introduce meaning to scopes.

Unscoped objects can be provided from any component if their dependencies are available. Since they are unscoped there will be a new object created every time that you call their provider. A scoped object will share the lifecycle of the component of the same scope and it will only ever be created *once* per component. If you recreate the component, you recreate all the objects within its scope. This is where things would get tricky.

Say you have the following setup: a component, and a subcomponent, as it is often the case.

```
@Component interface MyComponent {}

@Subcomponent interface MySubComponent {}
```

Now let's say we have two classes, `Foo` in `@FooScope` and `Bar` in `@BarScope`. Both support constructor injection and both have the scope annotation on their respective class. Let's say we add a provision method for the two to our subcomponent:

```
@Subcomponent
interface MySubComponent {

  Foo getFoo();

  Bar getBar();
}
```

Now the big question: *Where do `Foo` or `Bar` get created and which component's "lifecycle" do they share?*

We do know that `Foo` and `Bar` are in different scopes but that's about it. If one depends on the other we *may* be able to deduce that one resides in the (parent) component and the other in the subcomponent since one can only ever depend on objects of the same or a higher scope, but this will only ever work for this simple setup and will leave us with uncertainty again if we ever decide to add a third component to this setup.

What happens if we have 3 scopes, but only two components? Which of the two components should host two scopes (if that even makes sense)? Or if it were to report an error, which scope is "the wrong one"? There would simply be no way of knowing for sure.

Those problems will disappear if you also add a scope to the component. It will now be clear which component handles which (scoped) objects, and it is easy enough to report errors when there are unknown scopes introduced.

Comment: I haven't learned about subcomponents yet so this might be the reason I don't understand the necessity.

Comment: Could the same be explained with component dependencies? Let's say I have an AppComponent and an ActivityComponent, as well as a constructor-injected object with a scope annotation on its class. Then the annotation helps Dagger figure out to which of the 2 components the object belongs? Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: @FlorianWalther Component dependencies are even more specific than Subcomponents in what dependencies they can use, so yes, I'd say the same principles apply. However your components relate, it would be impossible for a component to support the lifecycle of a differently scoped object

Comment: So it seems to me that the main reason for these component scope annotations is the possibility of constructor injection. I mean when we provide the object from a module, we already define to which component we want to add this module. From my understanding, this would theoretically make the scope annotation redundant. Is my understanding correct or am I missing something?

Comment: Let me ask differently: When we use Subcomponents, are there situations where a scoped object could belong to different components and there is no piece of information that would infer to which component this object belongs? With information, I mean things like the object's module added to the component, a provision method for that object added to the component, or any other piece of information that says "I want this object provided from this particular component".

Comment: A module can have provide both scoped and unscoped objects, so you'd need some scope annotation to differentiate between those two. Further, a module may be added to multiple components, possibly of different scopes, here again it would be hard to verify that everything was correct. A provision method does not define a scope either. It may also provide unscoped objects, or objects from parent components or component dependencies with a completely different scope as well

Answer (score 0):

We need localization because we do not want all our dependencies to live as long as the application, and there are cases when we want our dependencies to not share the same state by being the same object.
Activities have their own Presenters or ViewModels, 1 or more Presenters or ViewModels may require a single Interactor and Interactors depends on the data layer. Dagger 2 provides @Scope as a mechanism to handle scoping. Scoping allows you to preserve the object instance and provide it as a local singleton for the duration of the scoped component.
 Scopes cares about keeping single instance of class as long as its scope exists. In practice it means that instances scoped in @ApplicationScope lives as long as Application object. @ActivityScope keeps references as long as Activity exists (for example we can share single instance of any class between all fragments hosted in this Activity).
In short - scopes give us “local singletons” which live as long as scope itself.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough. I want to understand why Dagger explicitly needs the scope annotation on the component in order to work.